# How to change label with as as character?

Tags: r, label

I have read csv file

```
    X       Date Price.Dollars.per.Thousand.Cubic.Feet
1     0 2002-01-15                                  3.10
2     1 2002-02-15                                  2.86
3     2 2002-03-15                                  3.37
4     3 2002-04-15                                  3.80
5     4 2002-05-15                                  3.78
6     5 2002-06-15                                  3.61
7     6 2002-07-15                                  3.49
```

I want to use ggplot2 for plotting.
This works fine

```
piz$Date = as.Date(piz$Date)
```

But when I try

```
piz$prices = as.character( Price Dollars per Thousand Cubic Feet)
```

I have problems

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "piz$prices = as.character( Price Dollars"
```

This does not work either

```
piz$prices = as.character(piz$ Price Dollars per Thousand Cubic Feet)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use "." instead " ":

```
piz$prices<- as.character(piz$"Price.Dollars.per.Thousand.Cubic.Feet")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because R has replaced the spaces in your column name with ".". The following should work.

```
piz$prices = as.character(piz$Price.Dollars.per.Thousand.Cubic.Feet)
```